# Error: "El recurso requerido no está disponible" con Tomcat y Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Buenas a todos, estoy desarrollando un pequeño proyecto en Spring MVC y Tomcat, de momento solo tengo hecho el login y la página principal, a la cual se redirige después de iniciar sesión. Os pongo el contenido de mis archivos para que me echeis una mano, ya que he mirado por ahí y no logro sacar cual puede ser el error:

**web.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="3.1">
     <display-name>WebProject</display-name>
     <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-
      class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- 
    class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/config-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:configApplication.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
  </web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>TPV Cocoa</title>
<style>
    .formulario{
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class="text-center">Inicia sesión en TPV Cocoa</h1>
<form action="login.do" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">  
        <div class="formulario form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon 
 glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="user" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="user" placeholder="Usuario" value=""> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon 
  glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" 
  name="password" placeholder="Password" value=""> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <c:out value="${requestScope.error}"/>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Iniciar 
     sesión"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </form>
   <div id="avisos" style="color:red"><?php echo $avisos ?></div>
 </div>
 <script>document.getElementById('usuario').focus();</script>   
  </body>
   </html>
```

**UserController**(Controlador que uso para el login)

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan("cocoa.tpv.controllers")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserFacade userService;


@RequestMapping("login.do")
public ModelAndView loginUsuario(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();

    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    User user=new User();

    String userName=request.getParameter("user");
    String userPassword=request.getParameter("password");

    try{
        user.setName(userName);
        user.setPassword(userPassword);

        User usuarioLogged=userService.getUser(user);

        if(usuarioLogged == null){
            modelAndView.setViewName("index.jsp");
        }else{
            modelAndView.setViewName("main.jsp");
            modelAndView.addObject("usuarioLogged", usuarioLogged);
        }

    }catch(MainException excepcion){
        modelAndView.setViewName("index.jsp");
        modelAndView.addObject("error", excepcion.getMessage());
    }

    return modelAndView;

}
}
```

Mi proyecto está estructurado así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que, cuando intento realizar el inicio de sesión me salta el error HTTP-404, y dice que el recurso requerido no está disponible, la verdad es que no encuentro donde está el fallo. Para que funcione debería ir a main.jsp si el login es correcto y si no, quedarse en index.jsp y mostrar un error.
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿A qué URL intentas acceder?

Comment: No intento acceder a ninguna URL por así decirlo, si no a la página que me redirecciona el Controller usando ModelAndView. Si es correcto que vaya a main.jsp y si no es correcto que vuelva a index.jsp mostrando un error

Comment: Sigue abierta esta pregunta?
Donde está ubicado el archivo index.jsp ?